# Powering the Arcology great works

Tags: simcity-2013

I just finished my first ever Arcology great works.
But it seems to need power, which makes perfectly good sence.

**How does the Arcology get its power demand met?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need surplus power in a city in the same cluster as the Arcology. The power is transferred automatically.

You may need more than the exact amount of surplus power. Power transfer is not 100% efficient.